# Como reduzir o tempo de criação e gravação de uma imagem Linux para uso no RapsberryPi?

Tags: shell, apple, raspberry-pi

Estou retomando um projeto no qual preciso do RapsberryPi, porém na última tentativa para criar uma imagem é gravá-la no SdFlash, utilizando o comando DD, o processo levou horas para concluir, acabei deixando e não contabilizei o tempo mas farei novamente este fim de semana e atualizo esta dúvida.

É importante salientar que estou usando o Mac, até onde tenho conhecimento os comandos do Shel, não tem nenhuma diferença, e este em especial não tem nenhum bug que possa levar a esta demora.

Outro dado importante, a imagem usada foi criada com 32GB.

O cartão é um Kingston SD HC 32GB

[mac](/questions/tagged/mac)

Answer (score 1):

Qual a marca do seu cartão? A primeira vez que eu tentei gravar a imagem do Raspberry Pi (também num Mac), eu usei um cartão Kingston no qual eu só conseguia gravar a 300 KB/s. Eu comprei um cartão ADATA Class 10, e agora eu gravo a 10 MB/s, que é uma velocidade bem mais razoável — a imagem do Raspberry Pi não ocupa os 16 GB, mas demoraria meia hora pra gravar a totalidade do cartão.

[Aqui](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards#SD_card_performance) tem uma amostragem das marcas de cartões com as respectivas velocidades.